# Close window without displaying "Are you sure" dialog box

Tags: javascript

I have a form. If I try to close it, it shows a dialog box that says:

> Are you sure you want to leave this page?

Javascript:

```
window.parent.location.close();
```

Is there a way i can close this window without displaying the dialog box?

Comment: If your page is showing that, it means that something else on your page has a "beforeunload" handler set up. Just get rid of that if you don't want it.

Comment: @Pointy:Thanks for the answer.The dialog comes up when I click 'X' button to close.Do you think handling 'beforeunload' will work still?

Comment: If there's a "beforeunload" handler, you get that popup. If there isn't, you don't.  You can't have a "beforeunload" handler and **not** get the popup.

Comment: @Pointy:There`s call to a js function,When I refresh it goes to the function,but when I try to click on 'Close' button it doesn`t go to the function but still pop-up comes.How is it working??

Comment: I think you just haven't found the `window.onbeforeunload` function yet. Look at the code in included `<script>` tags.